# What are the arrows on my mschart

Tags: c#

Hello guys i have a MSChart and i have some arrows on chart exactly where the series are   overlapping  i would like to know at least what are they and maybe how can i get them out.

The chart is generated with two methods:

```
   private void DesignChart() 
        {
            // Create Chart Area
            ChartArea chartArea1 = new ChartArea();

            // Add Chart Area to the Chart
            chart1.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea1);
            chart1.Legends.Add(new Legend());
      //     chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format={"00:00:00"};
            chart1.Location = new Point(14, 494);
            chart1.Size = new Size(982, 224);
            this.Controls.Add(chart1);
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(chart1)).EndInit();
        }
private void SetGraph(){
.........
  for (int i = 0; i < chart1.Series.Count; i++)
            {

                chart1.Series[i].XValueMember = "Date";
                chart1.Series[i].YValueMembers = "Value";

                chart1.Series[i].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;
                chart1.Series[i].XValueType = ChartValueType.Time;
                chart1.Series[i].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;

                chart1.Series[i].MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Star10;
                chart1.Series[i].MarkerSize = 8;
                chart1.Series[i].MarkerColor = chart1.Series[0].BorderColor;
                chart1.Series[i].BorderWidth = 3;
                chart1.Series[i].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
                chart1.Series[i].ToolTip = "#VALY => #AXISLABEL";
            }

            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsMarginVisible = true;
}
```

Picture link [Photo of the chart](http://img845.imageshack.us/img845/8392/arrowak.png)

Thanks

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the chart?

Comment: i cannot i'm not allowed i don't have enough posts

Comment: @adisba: post a URL to a screenshot here and someone will edit the question for you.

Comment: picture link [link](http://img845.imageshack.us/img845/8392/arrowak.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible the 'arrows' are actually the result of this line?

```
chart1.Series[i].MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Star10;
```

Comment: Actually Steve is right  'arrows' are actually the result of this     chart1.Series[i].MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Star10;   if i put any marker style i have arrows anyway to get rid of them?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it happens because of this line:

```
  chart1.Series[i].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
```

If the data points are close together/overlap, chart control uses the arrow to point to the reference point so you don't get confused -- or something like that. Try setting this line to false and see if the arrows disappear. Not sure there is any other way to override the arrow display.